# Use resources of foreign maven modules?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use a resource from another module to import a file. My goal is to pass the filename by each custom class, and let the base class of another module fetch the file.

But I always get a Nullpointer Exception.
What am I doing wrong?

Module A:

```
src/main/java/foo/bar/MyBaseClass.java
src/main/resources/foo/bar/test.xml
```

Module B:

```
src/main/java/other/path/MyCustomClass extends MyBaseClass
```

classes:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
    public static String TESTFILE = "foo/bar/test.xml";
    getData(String filename) {
        InputStream inputStream = MyBaseClass.class.getResourceAsStream(String filename); //NPE
    }
}

class MyCustomClass extends MyBaseClass() {
    doSomething() {
        getData(TESTFILE);
    }
}
```

/edit:
should I maybe use something like this?

```
super.getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)
```

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` throws an NPE when the provided filename is null.  Are you sure the filename you're passing in is not null?

Comment: Ah did you add the dependency to module A in your module B

Comment: super.getClass() will return the same result as getClass().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely you should be using [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

e.g.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
```

(probably safer, might work in different environments more correctly, i.e., where a special classloader is being used, Java EE?)

or at least

```
aClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
```

this is how you should load resources on the classpath which may be in a different JAR (or classpath entry) than the given class you're calling getResourceXXX on.

If you're using a class that's in module B and you want to load resources from module A, you need to use ClassLoader.getResourceXXX.

So in Java you should generally use this approach (unless you care about restricting resource loading to a smaller area...)

Another thing to be careful about: pay attention to the need for a leading "/", always double-check the javadocs of whichever method you're using

see also: http://www.xyzws.com/servletfaq/what-is-different-between-classloadergetresourceasstream-and-classgetresourceasstream/21

Answer (score 0):

The [getResourcesAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) expects a name which is **NOT** a filename cause it's a resource name. Furthermore it looks like you are trying to access a resource from an other maven module. And not to forget you are trying to access the resource via a relative path which should be changed into an absolute resources path like */foo/bar/test.xml* instead of *foo/bar/test.xml*.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to access a file from other maven module, that is what I'd like to do, and that's my problem!